# python lineplot with color according to y values

Tags: python, matplotlib, line

I am quite a beginner in coding ... Im trying to plot curves from 2columns xy data with full line not scatter. I want y to be colored according to the value of y. 
I can make it work for scatter but not for line plot.

my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib

read data ... (data are xy 2 columns so one can simply use 2 lists, say a and b)
# a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
# b = [11,12,3,34,55,16,17,18,59,50,51,42,13,14,35,16,17]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

bnorm = []
for i in b:
    i = i/float(np.max(b))   ### normalizing the data
    bnorm.append(i)

plt.scatter(a, b, c = plt.cm.jet(bnorm))
plt.show()
```

with scatter it works ... 
how can I make it as a line plot with colors ? something like this: 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to plot a gradient color line in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500700/how-to-plot-a-gradient-color-line-in-matplotlib)

Comment: The approach is to interpolate the data into higher resolution and plot it as a bunch of line segments. The color of each line segment is changed gradually according to your chosen colormap.

Comment: on the top there is an answer that "This question may already have an answer here: How to plot a gradient color line in matplotlib? " ... I checked it tried it ... but then I needed to plot it in 3d using mpl_toolkits.mplot3d and that returned me an error: 'LineCollection' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection' ... how can I fixed this ? thx