# python color polar plot with chromatic circle

Tags: python, colors, polar-coordinates

I am trying to plot numeric values of color in a polar plot with r and theta. I did that with the polar plot in matplotlib but I would like to insert  a chromoatic circle around or at least color rectangles around the circle in order to make the reading of the color easier. I drew an example (see image below)[image].

I have been trying with the code below, but I am not really satisfy with the results, would there be another way to insert such a chromatic circle or rectangles ? Thank you !
    r = np.arange(1,11,1)
    theta = np.arange(1,20,2)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')

rect1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((85.48,60), -50, 10, color='blue')
rect1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((85.48,60), -50, 10, color='blue')

ax.plot(theta,r)
ax.add_patch(rect1)
ax.set_rmax(70)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please see if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940285/plot-a-polar-color-wheel-based-on-a-colormap-using-python-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you very much, I can re use the code and get very close to what I want !