# Create color wheel pattern image in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, color-wheel

I am trying to create a color wheel pattern image of given width and height. Something like this:-

[image]

How can it be done in a creative pythonic way preferably using **opencv** and **numpy**?
I found some resources (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31942626/1167584)) where inbuilt functions of `matloblib` are being used.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific IMO. What have you tried to do this so far? Did you try adapting the code that you yourself has linked? Please try and if you run into specific problems when trying to do so, update the question with that.

Comment: this seems like a do my HW question. SO is meant to help debug and improve your code rather than coding a question. I suggest revisiting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I agree I should have mentioned all the things I had tried. Nevertheless, answer from Mark Setchell did help in producing the desired output with minimum lines of python code. Thanks for your comments. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilising the cues in Mark Setchell's answer, I am able to generate a color wheel based image of given width and height.

Hue:-

```
hue = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: (np.arctan2(i-img_height/2, img_width/2-j) + np.pi)*(180/np.pi)/2,
                              (img_height, img_width), dtype=np.float)
```

[image]

Saturation:-

```
saturation = np.ones((img_height, img_width)) * 255
```

[image]

Value:-

```
value = np.ones((img_height, img_width)) * 255
```

[image]

Below is a working code of the same:-

```
def make_color_wheel_image(img_width, img_height):
    """
    Creates a color wheel based image of given width and height
    Args:
        img_width (int):
        img_height (int):

    Returns:
        opencv image (numpy array): color wheel based image
    """
    hue = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: (np.arctan2(i-img_height/2, img_width/2-j) + np.pi)*(180/np.pi)/2,
                          (img_height, img_width), dtype=np.float)
    saturation = np.ones((img_height, img_width)) * 255
    value = np.ones((img_height, img_width)) * 255
    hsl = np.dstack((hue, saturation, value))
    color_map = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(hsl, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return color_map
```

Resultant Image:
[image]

Comment: Well done and thank you for sharing back with the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: FWIW, on my machine this is 10x faster... `saturation = np.full((img_height, img_width), 255.0, dtype=np.float32)`, i.e. 29µs vs 280µs for 640x480 image.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to think what values you will need in HSV colourspace, and generate those three single-channel layers:

Hue:

[image]

Be very careful with the Hue in **OpenCV**. If your Numpy `dtype` is `np.float`, use a range of 0..360. If your Numpy `dtype` is `np.uint8`, use a range of 0..180.

Saturation:

[image]

Value:

[image]

Then combine them using:

```
HSL = np.dstack((Hue, Saturation, Value))
```

And convert the result from HSV to BGR colourspace:

```
wheel = cv2.cvtColor(... cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide some more details on how did you generate the 1st image under HUE?

Comment: I've got to leave you a little bit to do! The value of each pixel is determined solely by the angle it makes with the 3 o'clock position - which you can get with `arctan2()`... so, use `np.linspace()`, then `np.meshgrid()` then `np.arctan2()`. Or use `np.fromfunction()`.

Comment: Thanks for point me to the correct direction. Utilising your answer, I am able to get the desired output. I'll also post the code as an answer so that others may also get benefited.