# How to mark rgb colors on a colorwheel in python?

Tags: python, colors

Given `(255,0,255)`, how can I output a colorwheel where this value is marked?

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to output it? In an image file? On the screen? Using which graphics or GUI library?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Each of your questions is a textbook reason for asking AI right away instead of SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code to achieve your purpose.

**Explanation:**

1. I have defined the `plot_color_marker` function, which takes an RGB color as input:

   1. Convert the RGB color to HSV color space using `mpl.colors.rgb_to_hsv`.
   2. Calculate the angle on the color wheel by multiplying the hue value (first element of the HSV tuple) by `2 * π`.
   3. Plot a square marker (`marker='s'`) with the specified size (`markersize=5`), color (`color=rgb_color`), border color (`markeredgecolor='yellow'`), and border width (`markeredgewidth=2`) at the calculated angle and a fixed radius (0.5) on the polar plot.
2. Next step is to create a polar plot by adding a new set of axes to the figure with `projection='polar'`. The `_direction` attribute is set to `2 * π` to make the plot go clockwise.
3. Then created a color normalization object to map values from 0 to 2 * π.
4. Create a color wheel using the HSV color map with 2056 quantization steps and the previously defined normalization object. The color wheel is plotted as a horizontal colorbar on the polar plot.
5. I created a color normalization object to map values from 0 to 2 * π.
6. Next step was to create a color wheel using the HSV color map with 2056 quantization steps and the previously defined normalization object. The color wheel is plotted as a horizontal colorbar on the polar plot.
7. Then I hid the colorbar's outline and the polar plot's axis labels.
8. Defined the user-provided RGB color as a tuple (in this case, `(255, 0, 255)`). You can try modifying this as per your needs.
9. Normalized the user-provided RGB color by dividing each component by 255.
10. Call the `plot_color_marker` function with the normalized RGB color to plot the marker on the color wheel.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib as mpl

def plot_color_marker(rgb_color):
    hsv_color = mpl.colors.rgb_to_hsv(rgb_color)
    angle = hsv_color[0] * 2 * np.pi
    display_axes.plot(angle, 0.5, marker='s', markersize=5, color=rgb_color, 
     markeredgecolor='yellow', markeredgewidth=2)

fig = plt.figure()

display_axes = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], projection='polar')
display_axes._direction = 2*np.pi

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(0.0, 2*np.pi)

quant_steps = 2056
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(display_axes, cmap=cm.get_cmap('hsv',quant_steps),
                                   norm=norm,
                                   orientation='horizontal')

cb.outline.set_visible(False)                                 
display_axes.set_axis_off()

user_rgb_color = (255, 0, 255) # Provide the RGB color here. You can modify it as per your usecase.
normalized_rgb_color = tuple(x / 255.0 for x in user_rgb_color)
plot_color_marker(normalized_rgb_color)

plt.show()
```

[Code demo](https://replit.com/@msankrit/Python#main.py)

References:

1. [plot-a-polar-color-wheel-based-on-a-colormap-using-python-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31942626/19090048)

Comment: Why is every color marked at a radius of 0.5?

Comment: @pho thanks for pointing it out and thanks a lot for editing the answer. I hardcoded it so for my case the marker will always be plotted at a radius of `0.5`. This can be made dynamic also if need be. We can use the saturation component from `hsv_color` as radius

Comment: @mandy8055 Maybe you're interested in my follow-up question as well: [How to add brightness to a colorwheel in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77401727/how-to-add-brightness-to-a-colorwheel-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)