# How to add brightness to a colorwheel

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

Using the code from this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77396626/how-to-mark-rgb-colors-on-a-colorwheel-in-python/77396970#77396970) from [mandy8055](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19090048/mandy8055), I'm able to mark a color on a colorwheel.
But **the information in the marker's position** is the colour's brightness.

For example:
*dark red* `(92, 4, 12)`:
[image: first screenshot]
*red* `(255,0,0)`
[image: second screenshot]

My understanding is that in addition to the colours angle another factor (distance?) must come into the calculation of the marker's position.

How can I add brightness to the wheel in order to consider a colour's lightness or saturation e.g. (I presume the figure below is based on colorsys):
[image]

Comment: Just scale down the values to decrease brightness, e.g. putting the center with (0,0,0). Saturation: calculate the average value of all channels (possibly excluding the channel with 0), and interpolate the grey with such value (so the triplet with such value) in center, to the initial colour.

Comment: But there are many decision you should take. There is no unique colour wheel (check just the saturated colours: often you see a different colour wheel, where yellow and blue are not opposite, so not good for colour mixing, but maybe more balanced on sensation). So it depends on what you want to tell readers.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you. I don't know where to start applying your suggestions. Do you know of any examples I could look at?