# matplotlib can't plot colored Hilbert curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, hilbert-curve

I'm trying to plot a colored 2D [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) using matplotlib. After getting the `x` and `y` coordinates, a plain `ax.plot(x,y)` gives the correct curve, but if I want to color-code the curve using the technique introduced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941474/2005415), it gives me an empty canvas (so not shown).

Strangely, the random path as shown in the original answer works.

My code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as mcoll
import matplotlib.path as mpath

def xy2d(n,x,y):
    d=0
    s=n/2
    while s>0:
        rx=(x&s)>0
        ry=(y&s)>0
        d+=s*s*((3*rx)^ry)
        s,x,y,rx,ry=rot(s,x,y,rx,ry)
        s/=2
    return d

def d2xy(n,d):
    t=d
    x=y=0
    s=1
    while s<n:
        rx=1&(t/2)
        ry=1&(t^rx)
        s,x,y,rx,ry=rot(s,x,y,rx,ry)
        x+=s*rx
        y+=s*ry
        t/=4
        s*=2
    return x,y

def rot(n,x,y,rx,ry):
    if ry==0:
        if rx==1:
            x=n-1-x
            y=n-1-y
        x,y=y,x

    return n,x,y,rx,ry

#--------------These are copied from SO--------------
def colorline(
    x, y, z=None, ax=None, cmap=plt.get_cmap('copper'), norm=plt.Normalize(0.0, 1.0),
        linewidth=3, alpha=1.0):
    """
    http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb
    http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html
    Plot a colored line with coordinates x and y
    Optionally specify colors in the array z
    Optionally specify a colormap, a norm function and a line width
    """

    # Default colors equally spaced on [0,1]:
    if z is None:
        z = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(x))

    # Special case if a single number:
    if not hasattr(z, "__iter__"):  # to check for numerical input -- this is a hack
        z = np.array([z])

    z = np.asarray(z)

    segments = make_segments(x, y)
    lc = mcoll.LineCollection(segments, array=z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
                              linewidth=linewidth, alpha=alpha)

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    ax.add_collection(lc)

    return lc

def make_segments(x, y):
    """
    Create list of line segments from x and y coordinates, in the correct format
    for LineCollection: an array of the form numlines x (points per line) x 2 (x
    and y) array
    """

    points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
    return segments
#--------------These are copied from SO--------------

if __name__=='__main__':

    xs=[]
    ys=[]
    N=16

    for i in range(N**2-1):
        x,y=d2xy(N,i)
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)

    #-------------------Plot------------------------
    figure=plt.figure(figsize=(12,10),dpi=100)
    cmap=plt.cm.jet
    ax=figure.add_subplot(111)

    path = mpath.Path(np.column_stack([xs, ys]))
    #verts = path.interpolated(steps=1).vertices
    verts=path.vertices
    x, y = verts[:, 0], verts[:, 1]
    z = np.linspace(0, 1, len(xs))
    colorline(x, y, z, ax=ax, cmap=cmap, linewidth=1)

    #ax.plot(x,y) # this works, but with blue line
    plt.show(block=False)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

My setup:

- python=2.7.14, in anaconda 4.4.10
- matplotlib=2.0.2=py27h334a7c2_1, also tested 2.1.2=py27h0e671d2_0
- numpy=1.14.1

Comment: You need to set your axis limits

Comment: @DavidG Indeed! So `add_collection()` actually doesn't trigger an automatic limit setting.

Comment: You need to autoscale the plot manually. See duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working, however both the axis limits are `(0,1)`, therefore you're too zoomed in to see the plot. It seems that `add_collection` doesn't auto scale the axes.

The solution is to simply scale the axes yourself:

```
ax.set_ylim(0,15)
ax.set_xlim(0,15)

# or use plt.xlim() if not using object oriented API
```