# How do I use matplotlibs colormap alpha-values to make tripcolor plot fade to transparency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, alpha-transparency

I want to plot a probability distribution over a map using tripcolor and want the distribution to fade to transparency where the probability is low/zero. However tripcolor doesn't seem to accept local alpha-values provided by the colormap.

I set up a custom colormap that transitions from a transparent (`alpha=0.`) white to some blueish color (`alpha=1.`), as described in the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html).

```
cdict = {'red': ((0., 1., 1.),
                 (1., 0., 0.)),
         'green': ((0., 1., 1.),
                   (1., 0.5, 0.5)),
         'blue': ((0., 1., 1.),
                  (1., 1., 1.)),
         'alpha': ((0., 0., 0.),
                   (1., 1., 1.))}
testcmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('test', cdict)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=testcmap)
```

If I apply this to a line, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500700/how-to-plot-a-gradient-color-line-in-matplotlib)
everything works fine.

However if I want to use tripcolor to draw the distribution, it seems to ignore the colormap alpha values...

It works for a scatter plot.

A minimal working example can be found below.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, colors, cm

# quick and dirty test data
ext = np.linspace(0., 1., 21)
coords, _ = np.meshgrid(ext, ext)

x = coords.flatten()
y = coords.T.flatten()

vals = 1. - np.sin(coords * np.pi / 2).flatten()

# color dict
cdict = {'red': ((0., 1., 1.),
                 (1., 0., 0.)),
         'green': ((0., 1., 1.),
                   (1., 0.5, 0.5)),
         'blue': ((0., 1., 1.),
                  (1., 1., 1.)),
         'alpha': ((0., 0., 0.),
                   (1., 1., 1.))}
# colormap from dict
testcmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('test', cdict)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=testcmap)
# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_facecolor('black')

ax.tripcolor(x, y, vals, cmap='test')

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1)
ax2.set_facecolor('black')

ax2.scatter(x, y, c=vals, cmap='test')

plt.show()
```

**Edit:**
Looking at the [sourcecode](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/tri/tripcolor.py) [line 118](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/tri/tripcolor.py#L118) seems to set a global alpha for the triangulation. Copy/pasting the tripcolor function and omitting this line worked. However it would still be nice to use matplotlibs built-in functions...

**Edit2:**
Changed the data generation function from cos to 1-sin to get a more suggestive transition.
For the first edit to give a nice result I also hat to use `shading='gouraud'`.

Comment: Hmmm... when increasing ext = np.linspace(0., 1., 21) to ext = np.linspace(0., 1., 200) tripcolor does not look bad at all...

Comment: @Sosel tripcolor still doesn't show any transparency to me. The scatter plot appear more tripcolor-like, yeah, but using scatters as a workaround is not what I want...

Comment: With fine granularity both, scatter and tripcolor nearly look identical here, so probably I just do not fully understand...

Comment: @Sosel Can you look at the right edge in the plots? For me there is a sharp jump-like boundary between white and black in the tripcolor plot, while the scatter plot fades to black smoothly. This is rather different, even if I increase the granularity to 200...
**Edit:** It appears the cosine was not the best choice to indicate the behaviour I want, see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this closer to what you are looking for?

```
ax.tripcolor(x, y, vals, cmap='test', alpha=None)
```

Not sure why, but my guess is that setting `alpha=None` allows each triangle to get the alpha color from the colormap.

Comment: Correct, for most other artists alpha is already None, but for the `tripcolor` it defaults to `1.0` so one will need to set it to `None` manually.